# Example of a sigma compact space which is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

A search through this site yielded plenty of examples where a space is locally compact but not sigma compact, but not the other way around. The fact that there is a term of sigma locally compact suggests that there are counter-examples, but I am having trouble finding one. I would appreciate any such counter-examples.

Also I was wondering about the validity if the following condition would imply local compactness:
Let $X$ be a topological space such that $X=\cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ where $K_n$ is compact. If $\{K_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is locally finite, then $X$ is locally compact. This argument seems to work even if we have a general locally finite compact cover (every set is compact) and not just countable.  Under such conditions can we conclude local compactness?

Comment: Just as a hint for the future: There is a search engine allowing to search for topological spaces via their properties. See for instance https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=~Locally%20Compact%20%2B%20%24%5Csigma%24-compact

Comment: I did not know about that site, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first part: $\mathbb Q$ with the usual topology is sigma compact but not locally compact.